# Can't deploy hello-foxx app using Foxx-Manager

Tags: arangodb, foxx

I've been playing around with ArangoDB for a while and tried to follow [this](https://www.arangodb.org/manuals/current/UserManualFoxxManager.html) guide on how to deploy Foxx apps using Foxx-Manager. The thing is that I can't deploy a simple [example app](https://github.com/arangodb/hello-foxx) using Foxx-Manager.

I try to install it by using the following command:

```
foxx-manager install hello-foxx /example
```

And the following error appears:

```
Error: Cannot find application 'app:hello-foxx:1.4.1'
```

The logs say this app isn't found:

```
2014-06-30T08:22:25Z [25822] ERROR manifest file is missing '/usr/share/arangodb/js/apps/system/hello-foxx-1.4.1/manifest.json'
```

Actually, the `hello-foxx-1.4.1` directory isn't found within `/usr/share/arangodb/js/apps/system/` folder. If I check Foxx-Manager config variables, it seems like apps are placed within `/var/lib/arangodb-apps/databases/_system/` directory instead:

```
The following configuration values are effective on the server:
- appPath: "/var/lib/arangodb-apps/databases/_system"
- devAppPath: null
- logFilePath: "/var/log/arangodb/arangod.log"
- startupPath: "/usr/share/arangodb/js"
```

An ls on that directory reveals hello-foxx app is actually placed there:

```
$ ls /var/lib/arangodb-apps/databases/_system/
hello-foxx-1.4.1
```

I'm definitely missing something. What is the expected behaviour when installing apps with Foxx-Manager? What is the expected directory to hold apps installed via Foxx-Manager?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

sorry there was a bug in the hello-foxx app. i did just fix it and updated our repository. Could you try again?

Comment: Hi @mchacki, the app is now correctly deployed but for some reason, the endpoints aren't reachable (I'm getting all time unknown path error).

Comment: sorry made a minor mistake while adding the app to our foxx-apps repository... could you try again (it should install "v1.4.4") in case you get a lower version please try `foxx-manager update` before.